# How to run tests in parallel using Robot Framework Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm using the `Robot Framework` [Maven plugin](http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/) to execute my Robot Framework scripts. I'm using this plugin because some of my keywords are implemented in Java and packaged inside an external library.

I want to be able to run those scripts in parallel through Maven/Jenkins/Selenium Hub.

I think that the RF plugin Maven "out of the box" does not offer this possibility... unless I'm mistaken.

I also looked at the possibility of using [Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot), but I could not achieve to call Pabot from Maven.

Does anyone have an idea to get to run the tests in parallel?

Comment: You asked this exact same question on sqa.stackexchange.com. Cross-posting is discouraged. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/132201)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is cross-posted with sqa.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry Bryan I didn't know about the cross-posting... thanks for the link. I don't mind closing this question... can I do it myself?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? If yes, can you please share?